# iOS Objective-C blocks warning: Control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to use Objective-C blocks. I have method:

```
- (void *)getObjectsWithSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *objectives))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
{
    NSMutableArray *objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *url = [URL_CONSTANT];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username" : USERNAME_CONSTANT, @"password" : PASSWORD_CONSTANT};

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager POST:url parameters:parameters

    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObjects)
    {
        for (id responseObject in responseObjects)
        {
            NSString *title = [responseObject objectForKey:@"title"];
            NSString *description = [responseObject objectForKey:@"description"];

            Object *object = [[Object alloc] init];

            objective.title = title;
            objective.description = description;

            [objects addObject:object];
        }

        success(objects);
    }

    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        failure(error);
    }];
}
```

When Xcode builds this method, I am always getting this warning: `control reaches end of non-void function`

Where is the ind of non-void function? As far as I understand, my method is void...

Comment: Don't you mean "void", not "void *"?

Comment: I feel like an idiot...

Comment: The lesson to learn: Believe the error message. It said "... end of non-void function", therefore it is not a void function. Don't ask "why does it complain about a non-void function when I know it is a void function", but "why is it a non-void function when I believe it is a void function".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your method you say that you return a pointer to void `(void *)`.

Therefore, your method is expecting you to return a pointer to void at the end of the function.

Change to (void) and you should be fine.

**EDIT**

Although you edited the question I don't believe you still have the same problem with that snippet. Try to see if you have the `(void *)` in your code as well.